# Are both results valid solutions for the separable DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a separable differential equation (with no initial value)
$$dx + \frac{2z-1}{2-z} dz = 0$$

And the way my professor did it is
$$ \int dx = x + C$$
$$ \int \frac{2z-1}{2-z}dz = - \int \left (\frac{2(z-2)}{z-2} + \frac{3}{z-2}\right)dz $$
$$ = -2z - 3ln|z-2| $$

Resulting in
$$x - 2z -3ln|z-2| = C_1$$

The way that he did it is with both integrals on the same side.

What I did was first moved them to separate sides, with the signs changing as necessary.

$$dx = \frac{1-2z}{2-z} dz$$
$$\frac{1-2z}{2-z} = \frac{2(2-z) - 3}{2-z}$$

So then my integral becomes
$$ \int \frac{1-2z}{2-z}dz = 2\int \frac{2-z}{2-z} dz - 3\int \frac{1}{2-z}dz $$

The result being
$$ 2z - 3ln|2-z| $$

Rearranging to get the final solution I end up with

$$x - 2z + 3ln|2-z| = C_1 $$

The two solutions differ because of the manipulation earlier from changing sides and moving them back afterwards.

Professor's solution: $$x - 2z -3ln|z-2| = C_1$$
My solution: $$x - 2z + 3ln|2-z| = C_1 $$

My question is, are both of these valid solutions? The domain where $ln$ is defined is different in both solutions.
If there is a mistake, what have I done wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to carry out the implicit substitution $u=2-z$, $du=-dz$ correctly,
$$
\int\frac{dz}{2-z}=-\int\frac{d(2-z)}{2-z}=-\ln|2-z|+C.
$$